# Execute PHP Script to handle ErrorDocument 500 for Apache2

Tags: php, server, apache2, fpm

I'm using PHP-FPM to host one of busy websites. I serve all php and html pages through PHP-FPM proxy. For 500 errors, I want to send Email to all stakeholders, with URL, its query strings and cookies through another PHP script hosted on the same server.

However adding `ErrorDocument 500 /report/webmaster/dp-server-error.php` inside virtual host results in redirect loop to error script i.e. dp-server-error.php. As work around, I have done something like this in virtual host file and it works.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.(php|html)(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/example.com/
ProxyErrorOverride On
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.example.com/report/webmaster/dp-server-error.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&cookies=%{HTTP:Cookie}
```

However, the work around has some issues. The cookies might exceed number of valid characters in URL. The URL might be noticed by one of the crawlers and crawling this URL might send false Email alerts. I want ErrorDocument to work normally without using the full domain name. I want to know how can I avoid the redirect loop. Also using

```
ProxyPass /report/webmaster/dp-server-error.php !
```

to avoid redirection loop is not acceptable as I would not able to use the existing PHP framework to perform detailed analysis of error before sending Email for further analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by “redirect loop”, are you saying you are getting actual 301/302 responses?

Comment: If I don't use full domain name, when 500 error occurs I get Internal Server Error with add on "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
Message in Apache error log - "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://www.example.com/"

Comment: And what does the error log have to say?

Comment: Message in Apache error log -
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: example.com